# D3 Collapsible tree: Scrollable container for tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am using D3 collapsible tree. And its size increase dynamically. Can I use a `div` tag and its `class` to make it scrollable? So that when size of tree increase it can be scrollable.

http://jsfiddle.net/bSQ8U/159/ is the problem example. Here when I expand all nodes. I will not be able to see full tree.

Comment: May be this link is useful. http://bl.ocks.org/CrandellWS/ca7e6626c9e6b1413963

Comment: No, The size of canvas is fixed here. When we expand all nodes, it will merge. I want to see full tree by scrolling if size of tree increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the height of the svg as it exapnds/collapses.

```
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var max = d3.max(d3.selectAll(".node")[0], function(g) {
      return d3.transform(d3.select(g).attr("transform")).translate[1];
    });
    //set the max of the group
    d3.select("svg").attr("height", max + 100)
    console.log(max)
  }, 800)//execute after 800 milliseconds after the update.
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b1e0nz3v/)

Hope this helps!